# How do public ssh servers like git@github.com automatically reject connections and send a message?

Tags: ssh

When I ssh to git@github.com, I get a message that looks like this:

`Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

The connection is then closed. **I understand this is intentional behavior**, but how do they do it? Is there a config option in sshd_config? Is it a different or proprietary package to manage ssh connections? How do they change the message to include the username?

I have no idea what to look up to find these answers. Any searches involving TTY allocation seem to only return troubleshooting for servers that shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either that the user shell is set to /bin/false (or something else that does nothing) and there is a sshd "banner" or "motd" (message of the day) that has that message,

or that the user shell is set to a program that emits that message and exits.

Comment: (I'll assume you know how to read the sshd docs for the word "Banner".)